# It is the case that $E[\exp(X)] = \exp(E[X])$?

Tags: expectation

> Is it the case that $E[\exp(X)] = \exp(E[X])$, where $X$ is a random variable?

I know this is too simple, but I must be googling the wrong things.

Comment: See Jensen’s inequality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't be true for a general random variable. E.g. if $X$ is a simple Bernoulli random variable: $\mathbb P[X=\pm1]=\frac{1}{2}$ then $E[X]=0$, $$\exp(E[x])=\exp(0)=1$$
and
$$E[\exp(X)]=\frac{1}{2}\left(\exp(1)+\exp(-1)\right).$$

---

If $T$ is a linear map then $E[TX]=TE[X]$, but of course $\exp$ isn't linear!

Comment: Aha. Thanks for the example.

Comment: What if X is Poisson?

Comment: @BenS. Even for $X$ Poisson, you won't have equality. As some others have mentioned in their answers, you'll only have $e^{E[X]}=E[e^X]$ if $X$ is deterministic (i.e., $X$ is constant -- no randomness).

Answer (score 5):

The exponential function is a convex function. So by [Jensen's Inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) 
$$\Bbb{E}(e^X)\le e^{\Bbb{E}(X)}$$

Equality will only hold if $X$ is degenerate.

Answer (score 2):

In general, note that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^X\right] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^x f(x) dx
\ne
\exp \left( \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x) dx\right) = e^{\mathbb{E}[X]}.
$$

It's easy to pick a counterexample, e.g. $x \sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$, then the left side becomes
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[e^X\right] = \int_0^1 e^x dx = e-1
$$
and the right-hand side is
$$
e^{\mathbb{E}[X]} = \exp \left( \int_0^1 x dx\right) = \sqrt{e}.
$$

If $X$ is a constant random variable, then, both sides will be always the same. More generally for equality you need a sufficiency condition that will equate the 2 above integrals.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be zero or one each with probability $1/2$. Then $E(X)=1/2$
and $E(\exp(X))=\frac12(1+e)$. Does that equal $\exp(E(X))$?